# google maps marker clusterer not working but no errors

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

This is my first experience with GoogleMaps/JS. 
My map is working as expected with individual markers. But when i add marker cluster function its not working and the best part is no errors on the console.

Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function CreateMap(rootElement,data,startPin,endPin){
 //console.log("startPin : " + startPin);
 var google = window.google;
 var map;
 var marker;
 var posInfoWindow;
 var markers = [];
 var markersArray = [];
 var mapElement = rootElement.querySelector('.my-map');
 currPos = localStorage.currentPosition;
 var currentPosition = JSON.parse(localStorage.currentPosition);
 var results = JSON.parse(data); 
 
 var defaultIcon, selectedIcon, mainIcon;

        function centerOnMyLocation() {
            closeAllInfoWindows();
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            posInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }

        function closeAllInfoWindows() {
            if(posInfoWindow !== void 0) {
                posInfoWindow.close();
            }

            markers.forEach(function(it) {
                it.infoWindow.close();
                it.marker.setIcon(defaultIcon);
            });
        }

        function showInfoWindow(idx) {
            closeAllInfoWindows();
            if(map !== void 0) {
                markers[idx].infoWindow.open(map, markers[idx].marker);
                markers[idx].marker.setIcon(selectedIcon);
            }
        }

        function highlightListItem(idx) {
            var items = rootElement.querySelectorAll('.my-result-list-item');

            [].forEach.call(items, function(it) {
                it.className = it.className.replace('my-result-list-item-highlight', '');
            });

            items[idx].className += ' my-result-list-item-highlight';
        }

        function selectMarker(idx) {
            showInfoWindow(idx);
            highlightListItem(idx);
        }
  
  defaultIcon = {
            url: "/maps/Locator_Green_Pin.png",
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(34, 35)
        };

        selectedIcon = {
            url: "/maps/Locator_Yellow_Pin.png",
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(34, 35)
        };

        mainIcon = {
            url: "/maps/Locator_Blue_Pin.png",
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
        };
  
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);
        map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 3,
            styles: [
                {
                    featureType: 'poi',
                    stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off points of interest.
                }, {
                    featureType: 'transit.station',
                    stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }]  // Turn off bus stations, train stations, etc.
                }
            ],
   'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
            scaleControl: true
        });

        map.addListener('click', function() {
            closeAllInfoWindows();
        });
  
  bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // MapAutoZoom : to fit the  markers on the map
  
  //alert("working on map");
  //results.forEach(function(it, idx) {
  $.each(results, function(idx, it) {
   
   //console.log("it : " + it + " , idx : "+idx);
            var labelXoffset = -30;
            var labelYOffset = -28; //reduce x offset to center longer labels 
         
   
            if (idx >= 9 && idx <= 98) {
                labelXoffset = -27;
            }
            else if ( idx >= 99 && idx <= 998 ) {
                labelXoffset = -24;
            }
   
   if(startPin<= idx && idx<= endPin){
    var m = new MarkerWithLabel({
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(it.Latitude, it.Longitude),
     title: it.MerchantName,
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     draggable: false,
     map: map,
     labelContent: (idx+1).toString(),
     labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(labelXoffset, labelYOffset),
     icon: defaultIcon
    });
   
    m.addListener('click', function() {
     if (idx !== -1) {
      showInfoWindow(idx);
      highlightListItem(idx);
     }
    });
    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: "<div class='my-info-window'>View details</div>"
    });
    var obj = {
     marker: m,
     infoWindow: iw
    };
    markers.push(obj);
     var latlongVal = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
      var markerVal = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlongVal      
       });
         
    markersArray.push(markerVal);    
    bounds.extend(m.position);//MapAutoZoom
   }
   if(idx== endPin)
    return false;
  });
  console.log(markersArray);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);       // MapAutoZoom : auto-zoom
  map.panToBounds(bounds);    // MapAutoZoom : auto-center
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "Me",
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: mainIcon
        });

        marker.setMap(map);

        posInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "My current location"
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            showInfoWindow(posInfoWindow, marker, map);
        });
  //
        // Custom Current Position Control
        //

        var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'goToMeUI';
        div.className = 'my-map-current-position-control-container';
        div.title = 'Click to show your current position';
        centerControlDiv.appendChild(div);
        centerControlDiv.index = 1;

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = '/maps/Locator_Blue_Pin.svg';
        div.appendChild(img);

        div.addEventListener('click', centerOnMyLocation);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(centerControlDiv);

        //
        // List item click event handling
        //
        $( '.my-result-list-item', rootElement ).on('click', function(event) {
   //alert("map result clicked");
            selectMarker(event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-map-list-index'));
        });
  
  function initialize(){
   var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersArray, {imagePath: '/maps/cluster/m'});      
  }
  
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  
}
```

Comment: You have one giant function, CreateMap. When/where does that get called?  In your `initialize` function, all you do is create your MarkerClusterer, assuming the map and markersArray are already available.  I'd say create your map and markers in that function too, first.

Comment: Instead of createmap function, i added all code into initialize function. Now the markers are not displayed properly.

Comment: Update the question with your new code